# "Method not found" on EF EnsureCreatedAsync at runtime

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-functions

I am getting the following error on EF `EnsureCreated()` at runtime -

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function:
> ExportFromCDSDayTime. DG.Extensions.Sharepoint.PowerHub.DeltaSync:
> Method not found:
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Operations.Builders.OperationBuilder`1<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Operations.AddColumnOperation> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Operations.Builders.ColumnsBuilder.Column(System.String, System.Nullable`1, System.Nullable`1<Int32>, Boolean, System.String, Boolean, System.Object, System.String, System.String, System.Nullable`1, System.String)'.

with a very simple model

```cs
public class PKSTests
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

and context

```cs
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity(typeof(PKSTests), build =>
        {
            build.Property(typeof(Guid), "Id");
        });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<PKSTests> PKSTests { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try to remove  modelBuilder.Entity(typeof(PKSTests), build =>
            {
                build.Property(typeof(Guid), "Id");
            });

Comment: Make sure your Entity Framework Core nuget references are all aligned on the same version - this includes packages you may depend on with embedded EF functionality (eek).

Comment: I changed my azure function to Net 5 and was able to get it working

Comment: Hi Poul, could you please post an answer in below area ?